# Loading a PDF BLOB from MySQL using PHP into a div or frame

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

Thanks for taking the time to read this question and possibly help - it is much appreciated. I have an application where I am storing PDF files within a BLOB field in a MySQL database (v5.5).

I need to query the database and then display this PDF BLOB and along with some other HTML content as well. So the display page needs to have mixed content - normal HTML & the PDF file. To do this:-
1. I have constructed my HTML page
2. I found this useful javascript at [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) that will help me display a PDF within a "div" but it uses a file link and not a feed from a database
3. I have written the query to extract the PDF BLOB as well

The place where I am stuck is that I am unable to mix content-types in the HTML page. If I print out the PDF BLOB using 'print' statement it just outputs garbage text. How do I set the content type of the div so that the browser will render the div in a different way as compared to the rest of the page? So when I print the contents of that PDF BLOB it doesn't render as text.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta>
    <title>View Detail - test UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/TestUI.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function (){
      var success = new PDFObject({ url: "/pdf/sample.pdf" }).embed("pdf");
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //calling php function to get object from session and populate it etc
    $file = get_cnd_detail($cnd_s);

    echo '<h2>'.$cnd_s->cnd_fname.' '.$cnd_s->cnd_mname.' '.$cnd_s->cnd_lname.'</h2>';
    echo '<p>E-mail: '.$cnd_s->cnd_email.'</p>';

    //OUTPUT THE FILE
    echo'<div id="pdf">'.$cnd_s->file.'</div>';
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add code snippets to show where you're stuck and what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix content-types within a single html page. There's one general content type for the entire page. You could use an `<iframe>` to slice out a part of the main page and have it contain some OTHER page, which could be your pdf.

And as for pdfobject, did you check if it could use a data uri? Just because the param says "filename" doesn't mean it won't be doing an HTTP request back to your server for `http://example.com/somefile.pdf`.

```
new PDFObject({ url: "data:application/pdf;base64,blahblahblah" })
```

might just do the trick.